# Is the part of Chrome that encrypts/decrypts profile not open-source? How come there is no way to transfer profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

For FireFox, I can simply copy the its data directories under `user\AppData` from old Windows to new Windows to restore everything exactly. For Chrome, that does not work. Doing so restores only profile names and most of the settings get lost. Even if I have been logged into the old computer, there seems to be no way to export decrypted profiles so that they can be imported on a new computer.

I have not been able to find any way to transfer profiles ("sync" is not an option) on the Internet. Why is this impossible? I have heard that Chromium is basically an open-source version of Chrome excluding some parts. Does the part that encrypts/decrypts user profiles is not part of the open source? If that part is open-source, can we use the method that Chrome uses to encrypt/decrypt the profiles to transfer profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile data is stored on disk in unencrypted format, but moving the folders alone
is insufficient. The secret ingredient is to also bring over the registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs`.

Here is what you need to do:

- On the source computer:

  - Save the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`
  - Use `regedit` to export the registry key
    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs`
    to a `.reg` file
- On the target computer (Chrome needs to be installed):

  - Ensure that all Chrome windows are closed and that `chrome.exe` is not running
  - Copy the saved `User Data` to the folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`
  - Double-click the saved `.reg` file and allow it to run
  - Open Chrome and your profiles should be present.

Comment: Oh, so, there is a way? I cannot test it right now, but I will test it later, and if it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: This is (no longer) correct by the way. Certain parts of the profile containing sensitive data are now encrypted. They cannot just be moved to a different computer/Windows installation. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239189

Comment: @DanielB: Are you saying this answer is not correct? I am confused by the phrasing with the parenthesis "(no longer)"

Comment: @Jim: I just copied my Chrome folder a few weeks ago and didn't notice any degradation or lost data.

Comment: @harrymc: ah so it works! What is the need for that registry key?

Comment: @Jim: That's so that the encrypted files can be unencrypted automatically when Chrome reads them.