# I have recovered data from my broken SSD, but Chrome doesn't decrypt my passwords anymore

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, passwords, chromium

I'm running Debian Linux and long story short I had an SSD failure. I have successfully recovered parts of my user folder, like the .config and .local directory.

I installed a new system on a fresh drive. I copied over my .config/chromium directory to the new user, but whenever I start chromium it gives me the following error on the console:

> ERROR:login_database.cc(1047)] Password decryption failed, encryption_result is 2

The browser runs, but all my passwords stored are unreadable by the browser, HackBrowserData and other tools only show garbage. The Login Data sqlite file has all the entries intact, but I don't know how does Chrom(e|ium) creates the key which is used to encrypt the entries. I have the

- complete .config/chromium folder
- complete .local/share folder
- complete /etc folder
- user login password

What else is needed, or what source does this browser use to construct its encryption key?

Comment: while the filenames are correct - and there's a file Its entirely possible its corrupted to the point data is irrecoverable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least previously<sup>1</sup>, Chrome and Chromium used to put the encryption key in the desktop environment's "keyring" (e.g. GNOME Keyring, or whichever other libsecret-compatible keyring is available).

GNOME Keyring stores its data in `~/.local/share/keyrings/`, usually there is just the single `login.keyring` in use. (You can use Seahorse or a very recent version of KeyRack to browse the keyring.) While it's possible to just put multiple keyrings in there, that won't work with Chrome as its special entry has no indication as to which Chrome profile it belongs to, so libsecret will continue pulling out the wrong entry. So you should instead move the existing `login.keyring` off to another place, put the recovery keyring in its spot, then reboot<sup>2</sup> and check if it shows up in Seahorse.

The keyring itself is *usually* encrypted using the OS login password, but if the passwords won't match then it'll just prompt you for the correct password the first time it's used, so it's not necessary to change it for recovery.

The specific entry that Chrome uses can be read using the aforementioned Seahorse or using:

```
secret-tool search --all xdg:schema chrome_libsecret_os_crypt_password_v2
```

<sup>1</sup> *(before I switched back to Firefox)*
<sup>2</sup> *(technically, log out, but there's some additional complexity related to that which I've no energy to explain so just go with rebooting)*

Comment: Seemingly the .local folder is not intact, so it's a lost effort. Anyways, thanks for the info, now I know that the keyring files are also needed in case of a proper backup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome/Chromium passwords are encrypted, and the encryption is
tied to both the installed system and the user's password.
This makes it difficult to migrate them to another computer.

Under Windows this is relatively easy, because the passwords
are stored in the Chrome folder of "User Data".
The encryption key itself is found in
the registry, so migrating both items migrates also the
passwords. (See [link](https://superuser.com/a/1602133/8672)
for details.)

For Linux, this is more difficult, as the encryption key is
hidden away.

The Github project
[ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords](https://github.com/ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords)
contains a python script to decrypt the password.
The script is written for Windows, but for Linux it can be
adapted. I think that most of the adaptation can be done by
setting two variables at the beginning of the script.

The script is explained in detail in the article
[How to decrypt Chrome password with Python?](https://ohyicong.medium.com/how-to-hack-chrome-password-with-python-1bedc167be3d).

There is also a YouTube video that explains the process at
[How To Extract Plaintext Google Chrome Passwords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=CIOsemj3kl4&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=JohnHammond).